# VS Code not autocompleting html

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have set up a new project to work on and have only created an `index.html` file and a `style.css` file. Usually, when I type `html` in the `index.html`, it provides options to create a basic template but I do not have those options, similarly, it does not do it for any `html` tags either.
I have checked that the language is HTML and not Django-HTML and also restarted the window but still no luck?

Answer (score 0):

It may not give any suggestions / autocomplete for tags in an empty file, since you're not inside any basic html structure.

Try `html:5` or `!` to create a html template first.

Answer (score 0):

try using html 5 `<!DOCTYPE>` or install **emmet extensio**n in vs-code

Answer (score 0):

check if you are using HTML and not something like Django HTML or so. It can quite often be the issue. Other than that, be sure to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` I had simmilar problems while I was using VS code, so this may help

Answer (score 0):

I installed the HTML Snippet extension, it was previously working before that without having to install the extension.
Reloading VS Code did not work, but after restarting my computer it worked!